# The tight bound for conditional mutual information: how much could conditional mutual information be greater than mutual information?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Given random variables $X$,$Y$ and another random variable $Z$, it is known that there are cases when the conditional mutual information $I(X;Y|Z)$ is greater than mutual information $I(X;Y)$.

For example, let $Y = X + Z$ and $X \perp Z$. It could be shown that:
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z) = H(Y|Z) = H(X) \geq I(X;Y).
\end{align}
**However, what is the upper bound of $I(X;Y|Z)$ given $X$ and $Y$?** We want to solve the following maximum problem:
$$ \max_Z I(X;Y|Z),
$$
where $Z$ is any random variable.

An upper bound (not necessarily tight) of $I(X;Y|Z)$ could be readily obtained as:
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z) &= I(X;Y,Z) - I(X;Z) \\
&= H(X)  - H(X|Y,Z) - I(X;Z) \\
&\leq H(X).
\end{align}
With symmetry, we also have $I(X;Y|Z) \leq H(Y)$. To summarize,
$$ \max_Z I(X;Y|Z) \leq \min\{ H(X),H(Y)\}.
$$
However, could the inequality above be an equality? **Or else, for any given random variables $X$,$Y$ (with given joint distribution), what is the exact solution to $\max_Z I(X;Y|Z)$**?

Comment: Are you interested in general case, or some example? Simple example is that, for example, two independent uniform variables have zero mutual information, but condition mutual information given their sum modulo max value (in case variables are boolean - it is just xor) is equal to their entropy.

Comment: I'm interested in general case. That is, for any given $X$,$Y$ (the joint distribution is known), I desire an solution to $\max_Z I(X;Y|Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I don't know the answer. Only a comment to note that, for the bound to be attainable, say, for having the equality be true:

$$ I(X;Y|Z) = H(X)  - H(X|Y,Z) - I(X;Z) = H(X)$$

... one would need to construct a variable $Z$ such that $X = g(Y,Z)$ ($X$ is determined by $Y$ and $Z$), but $X,Z$ are pairwise independent.

For joint Bernoulli variables we have the standard example: $X,Y$ are fair independent Bernoullis, and $Z=X+Y \pmod 2$. But I suspect that this is quite exceptional.